# Do .bat files terminate when piping an unrecognized command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, pipe, io-redirection

My batch file is prematurely terminating when I run this in a cmd.exe that is NOT an MSVC development command shell.

```
msbuild /version | find "Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16" >nul
echo did I get here?
if errorlevel 1 goto no_msbuild
```

I never get to the `if errorlevel` line, so I added the `echo did I get here?` line, and I don't get that either.

Here's the output when I run the .bat file (I removed the @echo off):

```
Wed 09/07/2022 10:37:49
D:\temp> msbuild /version   | find "Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16"  1>nul
'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Wed 09/07/2022 10:37:49
D:\temp>
```

It works fine when I run it in a VS2019 cmd shell (if errorlevel 1 test is false, i.e. errorlevel is 0, so find worked) and a VS2008 cmd (if errorlevel 1 is true, so find failed)

EDIT:
I eliminated the whole msbuild command/path issue, incorporating @mofi possible solution and came up with the following:

```
xyzzy 2>nul | find "abc"
echo hello
if errorlevel 1 goto no_xyzzy
```

The .bat file still terminates prematurely and never executes the `echo hello` even with the stderr redirection to nul.

Comment: There can be used `(msbuild /version) 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16" >nul` which __always__ works and `ERRORLEVEL` has the value `1` if either no executable/script with name `msbuild` is found by `cmd.exe` or `find` fails to find a line with the search string. Otherwise if `msbuild` could be found and executed by `cmd.exe` (and is not a batch file as then `call` would be needed) and `find` could find the search string, the __dynamic__ variable `ERRORLEVEL` has the value `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try and simplify this.

`xyzz | find...` is piping the `stdout` of `xyzz` to `find`. however, `xyzz` does not exist and therefore does not have `stdout` or `stderr` streams, so it will terminate. `cmd` however will produce `9009` errorlevel, but you did not request `stdout` or `stderr` from `cmd`, you requested it from `xyzz` becuE you piped it to `find`

To prove this point, we can eliminate `find`

```
xyzz 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 echo Failed
echo %errorlevel%
```

This will result in a result `Failed`.

We can however parenthesize the command and pipe the block to `find`.

```
(xyzz 2>nul) | find "abc"
if errorlevel 1 echo Failed
echo %errorlevel%
```

Firstly note, `errorlevel` is now `1` and not `9009`, not because `9009` does not exist, it existed inside the parenthesis, but `find` is overwriting `errorlevel`

Then, the reason this works is because the code block in its entirety is redirected to `find`, that means the `cmd` result as well, the entire block does not fail, only `xyzz` does and the execution of the block completes, but now the `find` query was not met and caused `errorlevel 1`

you can shorten this test by simply running:

```
xyzz 2>nul | find "abc" && echo success || echo failed
```

vs

```
(xyzz 2>nul) | find "abc" && echo success || echo failed
```

One last thing. `.bat` is the old extension of `batch-files` and it handles errorlevel slightly differently from the new `.cmd` extensions. So rather use the new normal.

Comment: The parenthesized version worked as desired.  For VS2019 command prompt, I get the proper `msbuild` to run.  For VS2008 command prompt and a non-VS command prompt, the `find` fails so I get my `echo ERROR! Cannot find "Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16"` command to execute.  Appreciate the explanation, in addition to the solution.